# Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código para un autoloader de clases

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className){
    require_once 'core/'.$className.'.php';
});
```

Todo bien hasta aquí. El problema radica cuando implemento las siguientes lineas para verificar que si la clase no esta en la carpeta `core` la busque en la carpeta hermana `controllers`

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className){
    if(file_exists('core/'.$className.'.php')){
        require_once 'core/'.$className.'.php';
    }  
    else if(file_exists('./controllers/'.$className.'.php')){
        require_once './controllers/'.$className.'.php';
    }
});
```

Es aquí en donde me arroja el siguiente error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found in...

La clase que estoy mandando a llamar se llama Route.php . Prácticamente, el archivo se encuentra donde mismo y a pesar de eso surge el error

Answer (score 0):

Revisando diversos post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927968/document-root-php
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930150/file-exists-returns-false-but-the-file-does-exist

Descubrí o almenos eso entendí, que para que funcione `file_exists()` debe de colocarse una ruta absoluta. Y esto puede ser solucionado con `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`
Además implemente un array para hacer el acceso de rutas más dinámico

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className){
    $sources = array(
        $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/app/core/".$className.".php",
        $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/app/controllers/".$className.".php"
    );

    foreach($sources as $source){
        if(file_exists($source)){
            require_once $source;
        }
    }
});
```